# linux (ubuntu) apache www folder access issue

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu

I'm a newbie in Linux, just installed ubuntu 14.04 and wanted to install WAMP (MAMP), I followed a youtube tutorial to install php5, apache2, mysql and phpmyadmin. Installed successfully both `http://localhost` and `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` works fine logged in successfully.

now I wanted to add some files and folders to apache www folder which is located at `/var/www` but cant create files or folders. I'm a Windows user where I usually keep all my PHP work in www folder.

I would like to know if there is a way to use any-other folder as www folder or how to create folders and files in that www folder. I reckon its permission issues, since being a newbie don't know how to fix that.. please help

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 14.04 runs apache as user www-data, you can change to this user using the command in terminal (shell)

```
sudo su
```

This will make you root and have access to /var/www directory, and you will be able to create files and directories.  Say you had a directory of images containing img1.jpg, img2.jpg, etc. in say /home/user1/images

as root you could

```
sudo su                      <- change to the document folder
cd /var/www                  <- change to the document folder
cp /home/user1/images/ .     <- copy what you need to copy
chown -r www-data images/    <- give the web server read/write permission to the folder / files
```

which will let you do access the images via a browser via the url

```
http://localhost/images/img1.jpg
```

Comment: thanks @dbinns66 what is this? what will happen if I do that?

Comment: Updating answer now ;-)

Comment: thanks for the explanation @dbinns66 I tried the first command `sud su www-data` and I get this error `This account is currently not available.`

Comment: Hmmm... I know it's availble under some flavor... in that case, do "sudo su" to become root, create / copy as desired, and do "chown www-data /var/www/<whatever_path>" to allow httpd to read/write to the files/folders.  Edited answer.. again... LOL

Comment: thats very kind of you @dbinns66 but i did not get it if i type `sudo su` and press enter on command line i presented as a root user. but thats not the solution. is there a way where i can change that www folder and create a new folder on my home or documents folder and use that as a www folder like editing config file or something

Comment: Read up on DocumentRoot here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot  ;-)  should be in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Comment: You are very welcome, glad to help!  I have one box at home set up with virtual hosts for a number of friends and their document roots are all /home/<username>/www ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that apache runs under different user (given your distro most likely `www-data`), while `/var/www` belongs either to the user or root.

So if you want to allow apache to write somewhere you have to give it permissions.
Since it is not good practice to give apache full permission to your disk, usually you would have a special directory where it can upload data.

For example creating directory
`/var/www/myProject/uploaded`

and then giving permission to all to write there

```
chmod 777 /var/www/myProject/uploaded
```

Alternatively you can change the owner/group with `chown`.

Comment: being a layman can i ask something how to create myproject and uploaded folder in first place?

Comment: You can create them normally via file manager. If you want to create them from terminal then use `mkdir` command. E.g. `mkdir /var/www/myProject`

Comment: no mate if i could create folder from filemanger or terminal I would have never asked that question... cannot create folder

Comment: aha, you need root permission. In that case `sudo mkdir /var/www/myProject` it should ask your for a password (as /var/www is root's folder). `sudo` gives you `root` permissions. However this question have been probably better asked over at SuperUser https://superuser.com/

Comment: chmod 777 is generally a bad thing, as is making items accessible via the web server owned by root... imagine someone finds an exploit and is able to create / alter a php file "dont_really_try_this.php" in you /var/www folder... which contains <?php system("rm -rf /*"); ?>  to give the web server the ability to write to folder /var/www/myProject/uploaded use "chown www-data /var/www/myProject/uploaded"

Comment: thanks @dbinns66 i've got that mental note so I wont use the chmod 777 command I also have made some note about my issue in your post regards :)